# Could not locate 'File' attribute of Google Earth using pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, google-earth, pywinauto

I want to use Python (3.6) and pywinauto (0.6.3) to control Google Earth (7.1.8.3036) in the Windows 10 platform to save the Google Earth image to a file.  I am able to start Google Earth from pywinauto and get the Google Earth dialog but could not find the attribute for 'File'. I did try use `app['Google Earth'].print_control_identifiers()` but could not see any attribute for 'File' (to long to include here).

I appreciate any help or suggestion how to do `app['Google Earth'].???('File -> Save -> Save Image...')`.  A simple alternate is to use hot keys (Ctrl+Alt+S) on the active Google Earth window.  I did try using `SendKeys('^%S')` or `type_keys('^%S')`, but those did not work.  I must not do something right.

Here how I tried to start Google Earth and find out if there was any attribute for 'File':

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start('c:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Google Earth/client/googleearth.exe')

app['Google Earth'].File.click()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py",
>   line 245, in __resolve_control
>       criteria)   File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py",
>   line 447, in wait_until_passes
>       raise err pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py",
>   line 351, in **getattribute**
>       ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)   File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py",
>   line 248, in __resolve_control
>       raise e.original_exception   File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py",
>   line 425, in wait_until_passes
>       func_val = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py",
>   line 209, in __get_ctrl
>       ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py",
>   line 84, in find_element
>       elements = find_elements(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py",
>   line 300, in find_elements
>       elements = findbestmatch.find_best_control_matches(best_match, wrapped_elems)   File
>   "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py",
>   line 533, in find_best_control_matches
>       raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text) pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'File'
>   in 'dict_keys(['Tour GuidePane', 'Tour Guide', 'Pane', '', 'Custom',
>   '0', '1', '2', 'Pane0', 'Pane1', 'Pane2', '3', 'Pane3', '4', 'Pane4',
>   '5', 'Pane5', '6', 'Pane6', '7', 'Custom0', 'Custom1', 'Custom2', '8',
>   'Custom3', '9', 'Custom4', '10', 'Custom5', '11', 'Custom6', '12',
>   'Custom7', '13', 'Custom8', '14', 'Custom9', '15', 'Custom10', '16',
>   'Custom11', '17', 'Custom12', '18', 'Custom13', '19', 'Custom14',
>   '20', 'Custom15', '21', 'Custom16', '22', 'Custom17', '23',
>   'Custom18', '24', 'Custom19', '25', 'Custom20', '26', 'Custom21',
>   '27', 'Custom22', '28', 'Custom23', '29', 'Custom24', '30',
>   'Custom25', '31', 'Custom26', '32', 'Custom27', '33', 'Custom28',
>   '34', 'Custom29', '35', 'Custom30', '36', 'Custom31', '37',
>   'Custom32', '38', 'Custom33', '39', 'Custom34', '40', 'Custom35',
>   '41', 'Custom36', '42', 'Custom37', '43', 'Custom38', '44',
>   'Custom39', '45', 'Custom40', '46', 'Custom41', '47', 'Custom42',
>   '48', 'Custom43', '49', 'Custom44', '50', 'Custom45', '51', 'Pane7',
>   '52', 'Pane8', '53', 'Pane9', '54', 'Pane10', '55', 'Pane11', '56',
>   'Pane12', '57', 'Pane13', '58', 'Pane14', '59', 'Custom46', '60',
>   'Custom47', '61', 'Custom48', '62', 'Custom49', '63', 'Custom50',
>   '64', 'Custom51', '65', 'Custom52', '66', 'Custom53', '67',
>   'Custom54', '68', 'Custom55', '69', 'Custom56', '70', 'Custom57',
>   '71', 'Custom58', '72', 'Custom59', '73', 'Custom60', '74',
>   'Custom61', '75', 'Custom62', '76', 'Custom63', '77', 'TitleBar',
>   'System', 'SystemMenu', 'Menu', 'System0', 'System1', 'System2',
>   'SystemMenuItem', 'MenuItem', 'Minimize', 'MinimizeButton', 'Button',
>   'Maximize', 'MaximizeButton', 'Button0', 'Button1', 'Button2',
>   'CloseButton', 'Close', 'Button3'])'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: First you need to expand "File" submenu. Google Earth is a Qt5 app so you can take a look at the WireShark example in the repo for guidance (it's also Qt5). Submenu can be expanded by `.invoke()` for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to save an image of a KML file in the Google Earth by using hot keys (Ctrl+Alt+S).  But this defeats the key purpose of using pywinauto. I am still looking for a better way to utilize pywinauto to control Google Earth.
Here is my python code along with comments:

```
import os, time
from pywinauto import Application
from pywinauto import keyboard

kmlfile = 'rcglic1457645225.kml'
kmlimage= kmlfile[:-3]+'jpg'
os.startfile(kmlfile)
time.sleep(15)      #wait for completely loading Google Earth

app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='googleearth.exe')    #connect to the Google Earth process
dlg = app['Google Earth']   #connect to the Google Earth dialog
dlg['Maximize'].click()     #click on 'Maximize' button of the Google Earth window to have the best image
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.SendKeys('^%S')    #hot keys to save the image (Ctrl+Alt+S)
keyboard.SendKeys(kmlimage+'{ENTER}')   #enter the image file name
keyboard.SendKeys('{TAB}{ENTER}')       #use TAB to select 'Yes' and replace file if existed
dlg['Restore'].click()      #click on 'Restore' button of the Google Earth window to go back to normal
dlg['Close'].click()            #click on 'Close' button
keyboard.SendKeys('{TAB}{ENTER}')       #use TAB to select 'Discard' and close the Google Earth window
```